# How to use a conditional operation for overgive a property to a vue component or user the default

Tags: properties, vue.js, conditional-operator

I'm trying to use a conditional operation to figure out whether I have to pass a property to a vue-component or even use the default value for the component's property.

Something like that:

```
<my-example-component 
:example-property="myValue ? {test: 1, example: 'test'} : *use default*">
</my-example-component>
```

You see my trouble^^

I know that this does not work in this way, but some of you may have a solution to fix my problem.

Have a nice day,

Markus ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by myself.

```
<my-example-component 
:example-property="myValue ? {test: 1, example: 'test'} : NULL">
</my-example-component>
```

I just commit NULL if !myVlue and the child component uses the default value for its property.

Kind Regards,

Markus ;-)